# What does the phrase 'in the case of'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

In this following comtext, what does the phrase ''in the case of'' mean?
Is it ''concerning or regarding''?

The contex:

> Nothing transmigrates from this moment to the next, nothing from one
> life to another life. This process of continually producing and being
> produced may best be compared with a wave on the ocean. **In the case
> of** a wave there is not the smallest quantity of water that actually
> travels over the surface of the sea.

Source:
Page.8
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: What [research](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/case?q=CAsE) have you done?

Comment: Two dictionary gave mentioned meaanings, but I don't satisfy the meanings in this context, and I'm not sure either of them fit in here.

Comment: It would help if you included the information about your researches in the question so that (a) people have more information about why you are puzzled, (b) you reduce the risk of being closed for lack of clarity or lack of effort.

Answer (score 1):

> Case
>
> Meaning of case in English
>
> noun (SITUATION)
>
> a particular situation or example of something:

[Case (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/case)

In the **situation of a wave** there is not the smallest quantity of water that actually travels over the surface of the sea.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Harvey. Isn't it phrase? Can we get it separately?

Comment: 'In the case of' is a phrase, yes. Did you mean break it up? **In** (preposition meaning 'connected with') **the**  (definite article) **case** (noun, situation) **of** (preposition used to show possession or belonging)